# Spring Batch - Save "onSkipInRead" throwable message in EXIT_MESSAGE of batch_step_execution table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I want which records were skipped during reading and insert that in "EXIT_MESSAGE" of batch_step_execution. So, this is my "SkipListener" class.

```
public class IntroductionSkipListener {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(IntroductionSkipListener.class);

@OnSkipInRead
public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
    LOG.error("Item was skipped in read due to: " + t.getMessage());
}

@OnSkipInWrite
public void onSkipInWrite(Introduction item, Throwable t) {
    LOG.error("Item " + item + " was skipped in write due to : " + t.getMessage());
}

@OnSkipInProcess
public void onSkipInProcess(Introduction item, Throwable t) {
    LOG.error("Item " + item + " was skipped in process due to: " + t.getMessage());

}
```

I want the following throwable message to be saved in the table.

```
    2019-01-30 15:37:53.339 ERROR 10732 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.a.b.config.IntroductionSkipListener  : Item was skipped in read due to: Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[URL [file:E:/survey-data-repo/Web/Source_Code/survey_v0.12/survey-data/1546580364630/1.Introduction.csv]], input=[fa1e9a60603145e3a1ec67d513c594cb,as,1,4,4,New Salmamouth,Chauncey Skyway,53566,27.216799:75.598685,Aglae Rice,580242662,2,12/2/2001 10:01]
```

And make the EXIT_STATUS as "SKIPPED" or something like that. Is it possible ?

**P.S.** I am new in Spring Batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can cast the `Throwable` parameter of your `onSkipInRead` method to [FlatFileParseException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileParseException.html) and use that exception to get the raw line that was skipped and its number.

Now in order to change the `ExitStatus` to `SKIPPED`, you need to add a callback method after the step (`@AfterStep`) and set the exit status if some lines were skipped, something like:

```
@AfterStep
public ExitStatus checkForSkips(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    if (stepExecution.getSkipCount() > 0) {
        return new ExitStatus("SKIPPED");
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can find an example in the [SkipCheckingListener](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/SkipCheckingListener.java).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The above method works. A question though; I wanted to save that skipped line and skipped line number in some other table(custom) or at batch_step_execution table in exit message column. Is it good approach to save exceptions in table !